# dink with it -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Beginning Shell Scripting by Eric Foster-Johnson, John C. Welch and Micah Anderson (2005)](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0764583204.html)

Example:

> They leave things alone. If the OS wants swapfiles in /var/vm instead of a separate swap partition, they’re fine with that. If the OS wants to mount things that aren’t boot partitions in /Volumes, great! As long as they don’t have to **dink with it**, they’re happy.

Not sure what that means and how to understand it.

Comment: I believe the writer here (or an editor at Wrox) has (for some reason) Bowdlerized _"**dick** with it."_ I've certainly never seen this idiom in the wild.

Comment: compare **dinking around** -- to waste time doing something.

Comment: You can substitute **deal with it**, that is, as long as they are not required to do anything special or out of the ordinary to accommodate such vagaries, they're fine with them.